# Why doesn't photos send raw files to photoshop?

Tags: macos, photos.app, adobe-photoshop

I currently have both JPEG and RAW files in my photo library on High Sierra.  I want to edit the raw photos in Photoshop.  However, when I use the 'edit with' option Photos always converts the file to a jpeg.

It does this when I have used the "use RAW as original" option as often suggested online.  It even does this where there is no jpeg at all - just a raw file - creating a new jpeg to pass to photoshop.

Is there any way to get the 'edit with' menu option to pass the raw file to Photoshop directly?

Comment: related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297254/photos-plugins-use-tiff-instead-of-jpg-as-interchange-format